# Advice to add `set nocompatible` as first line of .vimrc

Tags: vimrc, history-of, original-vim, set, default-settings

I recall (perhaps in the early 2000's) having `set nocompatible` as the first line of my vimrc and most Vim guides and tutorials recommending that practice.

Some examples I could easily find online:

- [`vimrc` file of Alex Quinn](https://engineering.purdue.edu/ece264/16au/static/.vimrc.html) starts with:

```
set nocompatible " Use VIM settings rather than Vi settings; this *must* be
                 " first in .vimrc
```

- [How I boosted my Vim](https://nvie.com/posts/how-i-boosted-my-vim/) blog article:

> Before doing anything else, make sure you have the following line in your .vimrc file:
>
> ```
> " This must be first, because it changes other options as side effect
> set nocompatible
> ```

However, that advice doesn't seem to make much sense these days, since [`nocompatible` is automatically used whenever a user .vimrc file is found](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#compatible-default), so there doesn't seem to be any compelling reason to use `set nocompatible` *in* your user .vimrc file.

When was this practice necessary? Was the default to nocompatible when user vimrc is found changed in a specific version of Vim, such that setting `nocompatible` was necessary in previous versions of Vim? Is there any advantages or side-effects of an explicit `set nocompatible` that I'm perhaps missing?

While researching this subject, I found:

- References to this being necessary if you wanted to use that as a *system* vimrc. But that doesn't seem to be the case in most places, since the links above clearly talk about the user .vimrc file.
- Mentions of a specific Linux distribution (Debian) explicitly including a `set compatible` in the system vimrc file, which would *require* an explicit `set nocompatible` to counter the distro defaults. (Not sure if that makes sense.)

Is there some truth or merits to these points above? Or was `set nocompatible` in large part cargo culting?

Comment: The help file `options.txt` was added to git at 2004-06-13 (the 7th commit). It already describes that `cp` is off when a `vimrc` was found. That was v7.0001.

Comment: BTW: I was convinced to remove the `set nocompatible` from my vimrc by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54214893/7369280).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is there any advantages or side-effects of an explicit set nocompatible that I'm perhaps missing?

Actually, there are many side-effects. Every time `compatible` is set or reset Vim rescans all options (except "terminal") and switches defaults when necessary. After that it rebuilds quite a few internal tables for `iskeyword`, spelling, `vartabs` etc. (see `didset_options()` and `did_setoptions2()` in `src/option.c`).

So bare `set nocompatible` in user vimrc is rather undesirable (even though the difference could be negligible nowadays), and, if not dropped completely, it should probably be guarded with `if &compatible / endif` as in `$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim`.

> When was this practice necessary? Was the default to nocompatible when user vimrc is found changed in a specific version of Vim, such that setting nocompatible was necessary in previous versions of Vim?

I found the code to switch to `nocompatible` in v5.0 but not in v4.6. So I assume it's here starting from Vim5 (early 1998).

Also note that `&compatible` could also be set explicitly in the command-line (like `vim -C`), but I doubt it makes any sense to fight against user's will inside his own vimrc. Maybe just do `finish` then.

Comment: Thanks for digging this up all the way to Vim 4.6! After 22 years I think it's pretty safe for us to move on! 

Answer (score 7):

One reason you *might* want to include a guarded `set nocompatible` in your `.vimrc` is that `compatible` will not be automatically unset if you specify the `vimrc` with the [-u flag](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#-u):

> Using the "-u" argument with another argument than DEFAULTS has the side effect that the 'compatible' option will be on by default.

It's for this reason that I have this version* in my `.vimrc`:

```
if &compatible
  " Vim defaults to `compatible` when selecting a vimrc with the command-line
  " `-u` argument. Override this.
  set nocompatible
endif
```

However, I have literally never specified my regular `.vimrc` via a `-u` flag, and bearing in mind [Matt's note about the date in which this switch was introduced](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/25150/343), I think it's fair to say this is almost entirely a case of cargo culting**: I suspect it would take you a while to find a blog post stating this is necessary that predates Vim 5.

<sub>* As Matt also points out, an *unguarded* version is actively bad, because it has many side effects which you probably don't want in the situation where you re-source your vimrc in an already running copy of vim.</sub>
<sub>** And, being a pedant, I frequently do!</sub>

Comment: The argument of `-u` is indeed a good one. I, at least, try to always pair `-u` with `-N` though, which ensures nocompatible will be set together with the custom vimrc.